# Does a hummingbird just hover, or can it be described as, “Hovering stationary?”

Tags: synonyms

Any help with my question will be appreciated.

Does a hummingbird just hover, or can it be described as, “Hovering stationary?” 
Excerpt from my new manuscript."Hooter Hornbuckle and Barnabus Belmont. The Best of friends.
"*Then, with a buzz of her wings, and in the blink of an eye she had moved, hovering stationary once more in front of another grimy window pane."* 
James A Bresco

Comment: Should not the word be 'stationarily'?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly worth mentioning that the hovering is stationary. Although you can also hover from flower to flower (if you are a bird or a bee), adding "stationary" here can have an advantage:

It works well in your sentence to contrast the stationary hovering with the swift movement that preceded it.

Thinking about the buzz of the wings, though... those are flapping at a ridiculous speed even while the bird is stationary, one buzz more or less is unlikely to move the bird to the next window.
But that is probably me reading too much into detail. :)

Comment: No, *"hovering"* generally means *"stationary"*. *Oxford Dictionaries Online* defines [hover](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hover?q=hover) as "remain in one place in the air". But there's no rule in English against being redundant.

Comment: Generally, yes. But "hovering from flower to flower" yields enough results to warrant "hovering _can_ also imply movement", I think.

Comment: Hovering is stationary unless you say something like *"from flower to flower"*

Comment: Little I can bring against that... I bow my head and I edited my answer :)